# My camera and microphone are not working

Tags: microphone, camera

My camera and microphone are not working, They are not listed on my hardware list
when I open cheese I see this :

[image]

Is there anything that I can do ?

Comment: Please post the actual hardware specifications. How is it connected? If internal post the relevant results of `lspci` and, if external, the relevant results of `lsusb`.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?